# How do we prevent alt-tab switching from changing workspaces?

Tags: gnome, gnome3

Can we prevent alt-tab from switching workspaces in Gnome 3? I'd prefer that when switch apps with alt-tab, it will switch to the last used window of that app in the current workspace (it may be minimized, in which case it unminimizes it).

Answer (score 3):

Simply run this command from a terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.shell.app-switcher current-workspace-only true`

With newer versions of Gnome, this is a configurable setting so installing additional software is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install **Tweak Tools**. Then go to **Extensions** -> **Alternate Tab** and check **Show only windows in the current workspace**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks slybloty, but that changes the mechanism entirely. What I'm aiming for is to have the same alt+tab and alt+backtick mechanism, except for the scope of it to be limited to the current desktop. So, for example, pressing alt+backtick will only swap windows of the current app, in the current workspace (not all workspaces), but I don't want to use that alternate tab thing because it's entirely different. I wonder if there's a way to tweak (in a Gnome extension) the default mechanism's behavior.